# Source code location and explanation of vectorized array operations

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to locate the NumPy `.c` file that contains basic vectorized array operations. For instance, I'd like to know what piece of code runs when you do something simple like a scalar addition to an array like `a + 5` or perform an aggregation like `a.sum()`. I believe the ndarray object [gets declared here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L714).

I'd also like to know if any of the linear algebra libraries like BLAS or LAPACK are involved with these basic arithmetic operations? Is the code as simple as a for-loop iterating over a C array or is there some magical way that computers do basic operations on contiguous arrays without for-loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of that stuff is in [`numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src). This is a template file NumPy uses to generate lots and lots of very similar C functions. No BLAS or LAPACK calls are involved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. Just to be 100% clear - numpy uses a 'regular' for-loop to do things like add scalars to arrays and sum them up?

Comment: I think I am close to tying it all together. The sum array method is defined [in calculation.h](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L516) which calls the [PyArray_GenericReduceFunction](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L199). This uses a `NumericOps` variable. This is where I am lost. It appears that many methods are set with `PyArray_SetNumericOps` but I don't see where that function is called and I don't know how it links to the for-loops.

Comment: @TedPetrou: It's not quite as regular as the for loops you're probably used to, and it's not always one for loop, but most of the iteration is done with for loops. As for `PyArray_SetNumericOps`, that happens [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e332ba4314bf874b1c7d17d82a2f1bf1766ece69/numpy/core/src/umath/umathmodule.c#L420), in the initializer for the `numpy.core.umath` module.

Comment: (While hunting that down, I found there's actually a [Python interface](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/260f18c910175bcb6162feb363112929653276aa/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2988) `numpy.core.multiarray.set_numeric_ops` that permits overriding the defaults set by the `umath` initializer, so if you want to get crazy, you can redefine how basic arithmetic operations behave for ndarrays.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still not sure of the sequence of `PyArray_SetNumericOps` getting called to the 'reduce' operation getting appended to `n_ops.add` and finally the for-loops completing the action in `loops.c`.