# Possible to have logical operations (e.g. `ndarray.__eq__`) not return `bool` in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators, symbolic-math

#### Question

What's the most elegant way to have NumPy not always force `np.equal` / `np.ndarray.__eq__` return arrays of type `bool`, especially when `dtype=object`?

#### Problem

Project issue: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8315

We're presently using `NumPy` in a project, and we have symbolic scalars that we're using in the arrays. We define `__eq__` to return a formula - here's a simple class that kinda reflects it:

```
import numpy as np

class Custom(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return "eq({}, {})".format(self, rhs)

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

It appears that `ndarray.__eq__` is always converted to a boolean type, even if `dtype=object`, because it converts using something like `__nonzero__`:

```
>>> # Scalar case works.
>>> a = Custom('a')
>>> print(a == a)
eq('a', 'a')
>>> # Not what we want.
>>> av = np.array([a, a])
>>> print(np.equal(av, av))
[ True  True]
```

While something like `sympy` can certainly handle symbolic matrices, I'm hesitant to start mixing array / linear algebra interfaces. And of course, we could go the route of machine learning packages and implement our own (or possibly use theirs), such as TensorFlow.

#### Blind Hacking

Granted, we can make our own NumPy UFunc, which propagates the type we want:

```
>>> # Try custom ufunc:
>>> generic_equal = np.frompyfunc(lambda a, b: a == b, 2, 1)
>>> print(generic_equal(av, av))
["eq('a', 'a')" "eq('a', 'a')"]
```

We can apparently also override `ndarray.__eq__` using `set_numeric_ops` (but that doesn't affect `np.equal`), discovered thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602324/7829525:

```
>>> # Try replacing.
>>> np.set_numeric_ops(equal=generic_equal)
>>> print(av == av)
["eq('a', 'a')" "eq('a', 'a')"]
>>> print(np.equal(av, av))
[ True  True]
```

And then we can monkey-patch `np.equal`:

```
>>> # Now replace original ufunc.
>>> np.equal = generic_equal
>>> print(np.equal(av, av))
["eq('a', 'a')" "eq('a', 'a')"]
```

This kinda works, except it completely destroys the original `np.equal` UFunc, and gives me the heeby-jeebies that we have to mutate all of `numpy` to try and carve out functionality for one datatype -- it'd be nice to extend the existing `np.equal` to maybe teach it something else.

#### Next Steps

From looking at the C API, there's the function `PyUFunc_RegisterLoopForType` which can *add* to an existing UFunc, but I do not see an easy-to-access Python version for at least prototype.

A related fact is we're using `pybind11`, which has tons of convenient mechanisms for handling Eigen matrices and interfacing them with NumPy. We made a patch to allow for non-POD types to be converted to `np.array(..., dtype=object)` types (hence this whole question); however, this prevents the same memory block from being accessed, so we cannot use the `Eigen::Ref<>` casting that `pybind11/eigen.h` offers:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8116

I've been tinkering with the apparent test module in the numpy source for custom dtypes:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4092a9e160cc247a4a45724579a0c829733688ca/numpy/core/src/umath/test_rational.c.src#L1192
which I came across thanks to this post:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5719

From that, it looks like you can willy-nilly register your own UFuncs for a custom DType, so I'm going to try and see if that also solves this problem.

Comment: Honest question: why are you using `numpy` for this?

Comment: For now, just leveraging existing work. Our codebase is in (heavily templated) C++, `pybind11` already had instrumentation to interop with `Eigen`, and we don't want to do just symbolics - we'd like autodiff, and nominal double scalar types. Definitely not saying it's the optimal choice given the current hurdles, but I'd like to get something up and working. Also, about 5min ago I was able to confirm that defining a custom `numpy` dtype does in fact allow me to override the behavior of `__eq__` to return non-bool things (without monkey-patching NumPy itself).