# Nest captureless lambdas in C++ with functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr, stateless

#### Question

Is it possible to nest captureless lambdas when passing them around in C++?

From what I can gather, seems to not be the case; rather, it seems you'd have to make a template class, and define static functions, and then pass those around.

#### Background

Related to this post, for `pybind11`: [Possible to have logical operations (e.g. `ndarray.__eq__`) not return `bool` in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205075/possible-to-have-logical-operations-e-g-ndarray-eq-not-return-bool-in)

Basically, I want to see if I can avoid macros and still provide stateless functions (without any type-erased `void* data` shenanigans) to be used with the Numpy UFunc API.

I'm aiming for stateless, because it appears the API has some functions that can have the `void* data`, which I could use to pass another function pointer (or erased lambda with capture), but some of them appear not to.

#### Blind Hacking

Here's my hacking:

```
// Goal: Wrap a function of type `Func` without capture.
typedef void (*Func)();


// NOPE: `b` ain't stateless.
Func wrap(Func a) {
  return [a]() { a(); };
}
int main() {
  Func a = []() { cout << "A1\n"; };
  wrap(a)();
}


// KINDA: Compiles, but `a` wasn't a parameter :(
// - Could use arrays a constexpr indices to fake it :( * 2
int main() {
  static const Func a = []() { cout << "A1\n"; };
  Func b = []() { a(); };
  b();
}

// YUP-ish: Works, cannot deal with lambdas :(
template <Func a>
Func wrap() {
  return []() { a(); };
}
// - Cannot be in a class in function scope :(
void a2() { cout << "A2\n"; }
int main() {
  Func b = wrap<tmp::a2>();
  b();
}

// NOPE: Lambda doesn't have default constructor (but what else would it do???)
int main() {
  auto a = []() { cout << "A3\n"; };
  using A = decltype(a);
  Func b = []() { A a{}; a(); };
  b();
}
```

I see there's some new stuff coming in for `constexpr` lambdas, but that seems to be more about the return value being `constexpr`, not the definition of the lambda itself (so that it could be passed as a template argument or whatever).

Comment: How is `wrap` supposed to be different from just `return a;`?

Comment: Sorry, the functionality of `wrap` is just meant to trivially show nesting; it's meant to do a bit more. That being said, I ended up realizing that the wrapping that I actually care about actually can be type-erased with a `void* data` argument, so it seems that this hack isn't actually necessary (my bad...). However, I am still curious if there is an elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy a lambda into a static variable:

```
template<typename F>
auto wrap(F a) {
    static auto F b = std::move(a);
    return []() { b(); };
}
```

Each lambda has a different type, so for each lambda, a new static variable is created, since the function is templated.

Note that it only work if the passed callable has a different type. If you only use stateless function object, you won't have any problems.

As a safe guard, you can also ensure only captureless lambda are sent:

```
template<typename F, std::void_t<
    decltype(+std::declval<F>()),
    decltype(&F::operator())
>* = nullptr>
auto wrap(F a) {
    static auto F b = std::move(a);
    return []() { b(); };
}
```

The sfinae expression looks for the unary `operator+` that with catpureless lambda, and it also look for the presence of a `operator()` member of the lambda.

Comment: This is a horrible hack. It only works if you only pass in lambdas, and fails whenever you use other function objects. I love it.

Comment: @Justin yes indeed. I will warn about that.

Comment: Ah, awesome! Did not realize that! I wonder if there'd be a safeguard that you could use... but there's nothing I can think of atm.

Comment: @EricCousineau well, you could ensure only catpureless lambda are used.

Comment: Captureless lambdas do not define a unary `operator+`.  They define an implicit conversion to pointer-to-function, and overload resolution uses that conversion to select the built-in meaning of unary `+`.  Raw pointer-to-function types will also pass your `void_t` check, and give undesired behavior...

Comment: Fanciful! And I believe that I see @aschepler's point about the function pointers - the address wouldn't specialize the template, so you would get overwrites / ignored updates.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function is not a pointer to a function, it is an object. Although it can be converted to a pointer, it can not be returned as a pointer, like any local object can not be returned via pointer, a copy should be returned. Correct code is below.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*Func)();

std::function<void()> wrap(Func a) {
  return [a]() { a(); };
}
```

What about the last. You declared a "function" `a` here `A a;` but not assigned a function "body". Try this

```
int main() {
  auto a = []() { cout << "A3\n"; };
  using A = decltype(a);
  auto b = [a]() { A c(a); c(); };
  b();
}
```